# How can i close the mysqi_connection? And why is it important?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

How can i close here the mysqli_connection? And why is it important to close the connection?

```
include("mysql.inc.php");

$ID = $_GET["ID"];

$q=mysqli_query($link,"select * from messages Where ID = '$ID'  ORDER BY createID ASC LIMIT 1");

while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
$output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: How? Using [mysqli_close](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php). Why? Dunno, is it important? I guess if you have a connection limit, and lots of concurrent requests; but if you're site is that busy then you should be tuning your database to suit the workload anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the mysql connection, make the connection variable to NULL.

```
$link = NULL;
```

There is a **maximum number of connection** a mysql server can handle. So if the opened connection has not closed and new connection is being opening, the new connections fails when the number of opened connections reaches the maximum number of connections.
Refer this link: [Freeing memory with PHP](http://sanjaykumarns.blogspot.in/p/freeing-memory-with-php-var-null.html) for knowing the importance of de-allocating an initialized variable.